# Разница между методом init() и init(ServletConfig config)

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Жизненный цикл сервлета начинается с запуска метода init. В абстрактном классе `GenericServlet` объявлено 2 варианта метода: `init()` и `init(ServletConfig config)`.

В спецификации указано, что при использовании `public void init(ServletConfig config)` необходимо первой строкой вызвать `super.init(config)`, иначе `ServletConfig` будет иметь значение `null`. Это логично, поскольку в GenericSerlvet есть переменная `private transient ServletConfig config`.

Однако для удобства, можно использовать `public void init()`.

Откуда в этом случае берется экземпляр типа `ServletConfig`?

**UPD:** Можно поставить вопрос по-другому.

За создание экземпляра `ServletConfig` отвечает `контейнер`. Тогда почему при `init(ServletConfig config)` он не создает этот экземляр, а при `init()` создает?

**UPD2:** Когда какой метод лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне кажется, метод `javax.servlet.GenericServlet#init()` существует только для того, чтобы его переопределять. При этом он не абстрактный для того, чтобы сделать переопределение необязательным.
Метод `javax.servlet.GenericServlet#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig)` и так вызывает внутри себя метод init(), поэтому стоит пользоваться только методом с аргументом `javax.servlet.ServletConfig`, но переопределять для дополнительной логики стоит метод `init()` без аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Однако они оба не абстрактные. К тому же, непонятна логика почему стоит пользоваться тем или иным. Исходя из ваших аргументов, единственная разница - это лишняя строка в методе с параметром. Но это ничего не объясняет

Comment: Я специально обратил внимание на то, что метод не абстрактный для того, чтобы его не нужно было переопределять обязательно. Ведь не всем может понадобиться дополнительная логика. Меня больше смущает то, что метод init без аргументов не protected. Но в целом, такое использование кажется мне наиболее логичным.

Comment: вопрос то в другом. Зачем их два? Почему init без параметров это плохо? Почему пустой init() и init(ServletConfig config) отрабатывают по-разному если они не абстракные и имеют пустое тело в GenericServlet?

Comment: Два их за тем (но только по моему), что один метод интерфейсный, который с параметром. Его и стоит вызывать. А другой метод для реализации доп функционала инициализации. Но я честно говоря больше пользуюсь Spring, поэтому моего опыта в чистых сервлетах может быть недостаточно.

Comment: зачем его стоит вызывать, если они отрабатывают одинаково?(если во втором случае вызвать super.init(config)). И что мешает доп.функционал реализовать в первом методе?

Comment: Нет, не одинаково. Метод с аргументом сохраняет конфиг в переменную, а потом самостоятельно вызывает метод без аргумента. 
Соответственно, вызывая первый, вызываешь и второй. А вызывая метод без аргумента, нужно явно писать super. Но это все исходя из кода. Больше мне нечего добавить. Разве что первый метод интерфейсный, а значит его с большей верояностью вызовут или рассчитывают другие классы/библиотеки.

Comment: В дискуссии рождается истина. Вообщем-то разобрались. Я добавил в ответы то, что удалось нарыть по этому вопросу

Answer (score 0):

В интерфейсе Servlet определен метод `init(ServletConfig config)`. Изначально только его реализовывал `GenericServlet`. При создании объекта `ServletConfig`, контейнер сервлетов вызывает `init(ServletConfig config)`. Поэтому при переопределении, если не вызывать первой строкой `super.init(config)`, объект конфига не будет проинициализирован. Позже в `GenericServlet` добавили перегруженный метод `init()`. Это сделано для того, чтобы не приходилось постоянно вызывать первой строкой `super.init(config)`, вообщем-то для удобства. А поскольку в этом случае `init(ServletConfig config)` не переопределен, контейнер сделает своё дело корректно - дернет унаследованный `init(ServletConfig config)`.